# Getting a crashed program's command-line invocation from a core dump

Tags: linux, coredump

i start a progress like

```
./game config1 config2
```

then i get i core.xxx for example,i want to get complete path and args

```
gdb game core.xxx
core was gengerte by '/xx/xx/game config'.
```

the path is too long , i want to get the info like

```
   '/xx/xx/game config1 config2'
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: no,i want to get args about the core  by using file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i do that ?

You can't.

GDB displays info recorded in the `PRPSINFO` note, which has these members:

```
    char pr_fname[16];
    char pr_psargs[80];
```

Anything that doesn't fit into 80 characters gets truncated, and you can only recover it by examining `argv[]` (requires the code to be built with debug info -- `-g` flag) or by looking at the stack contents (requires understanding of platform-specific argument passing conventions).